# safari webkit box shadow doesn't work

Tags: css

I'm writing a responsive app, so i want it to work on every browser. I found out that using `box-shadow` doesn't work on safari, so I used `-webkit-box-shadow`

I tried to use it this way :

```
.adresseinput{

  height:50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px red inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px red inset;
  outline: none;
}
```

but it doesn't work at all, any idea why ? And how can I fix this?

Edit : if you want more precision, i'm looking forward to do something like a french city pannel in css (a white input with a red inside border that is not glued to the limit of the input). Sorry if i made an english mistake

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try ie. `z-index:1000`, maybe other elements around are covering the shadow

Comment: Well the red shadow simply doesn't appear, while it works on chrome or ie... z-index didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you read the notes and known issues listed [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow) you'll see that `0px` pixel blur-radius, blur-radius in general, and `inset` are problematic in certain versions of Safari.

Safari:

- 3.1
- 3.2
- 6

iOS

- 3.2
- 6

I would see if you can isolate the issue by testing against `inset` and blur-radius individually on your target platform.

Also mentions iOS 8 has a zoom related bug.

Comment: Even if i simply remove inset i don't have any red border :s

Comment: What platform and Safari version? You'll need to create a testcase, and hope someone with access to the same versions can inspect it.

Comment: It's an IPAD with safari 8.3 , so i'm not supposed to suffer ... doesn't work on another ipad with the same config